# Konesans Regex Cleaner Transformation

Tags: regex, ssis

I have tried using the Konesans regex cleaner transformation in that cleaner I want all spacial characters to be removed from my column,

I tried this code in regex cleaner

Match Expression:

```
!@#$%^&*_+`{};':,./<>?
```

Replace Expression:

```
""

http://www.sqlis.com/post/RegexClean-Transformation.aspx
```

Comment: If you want this to match any of those single characters, just add brackets to make it a character set: `[!@#$%^&*_+\`{};':,./<>?]`

Comment: Thank you for reply I want the column values to be same after transformation ie Input : B@R^T output : BRT can you please let me know what should be in replace expression

Comment: because the function is not taking blank replace expression

Comment: can you please help me i am stuck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've never used Konesans Regex Cleaner and I don't particularly want to download it, but as  per your comment I'll try to help.

Looking at their samples online, it looks like all you have to do is put

```
[!@#$%^&*_+`{};':,./<>?]
```

in the "Match" column, and nothing at all in the replace column. Perhaps an empty string - `""`

You can use [this](http://www.regex101.com) to test your find and replace regexes.

Here are a few examples so you can get a feel for it:

```
String: This #is &&%^an !ugly &$%^string.

Match: [!@#$%^&*_+`{};':,./<>?]
Replace: 
Result: This is an ugly string

Match: [!@#$%^&*_+`{};':,./<>?]
Replace: -
Result: This -is ----an -ugly ----string-

Match: [!@#$%^&*_+`{};':,./<>?]+
Replace: -
Result: This -is -an -ugly -string-
```

Edit: since you can't use the empty string, you can try this:

```
Match: [!@#$%^&*_+`{};':,./<>?]()
Replace: ${1}
Result: This is an ugly string
```

Edit 2:

```
Match: [!@#$%^&*_+`{};':,./<>?](?<empty>)
Replace: ${empty}
Result: This is an ugly string
```

This works by creating an empty capturing group, and replacing with the contents of (). If $1 doesn't get the capturing group in Konesans, I'm sure some similar syntax will.

Comment: but the problem here is it is not allowing me to leave replace expression blank

Comment: then just use the empty string: as I said, `''` or `""`. Maybe the setting you're using is wrong?

Comment: Both give me this result input: B$GT output: B""GT or B''GT

Comment: it is replacing the special characters with $1

Comment: Try my next edit. I'm sure that capturing groups are supported in some way. Either put the `1` in brackets, or do `edit 2` If that fails, try escaping the brackets with `\`. Beyond that, good luck!

Comment: will try, I have another doubt can you help me with that for example in a column if I have input B.R output BimRim should come how can we do it